# Execute if functions only once, even when timer calls the function multiple times

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

currently I have a timercallback which calls the autoRing function every 100ms to check if the condition is met (proper minutes and seconds), if it is met, it will call the function btnSound_click (which rings a bell)

Problem is, I want the bell to ring only ONCE (and then automatically ring again, but the time between rings that I need is 30seconds or more), but the problem is that autoRing is called multiple times and the bell rings multiple times in that 1 second timeframe.

So I press the button, this code is executed:

```
timerSound = new Timer(new TimerCallback(autoRing), null, 0, 100);
```

and my autoRing function:

```
private void autoRing(Object obj)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = timeWatch.Elapsed;

        if (ts.Minutes == bellMinutesFirst && ts.Seconds == bellSeconds || ts.Minutes == bellMinutesSecond && ts.Seconds == bellSeconds)
        {
            btnSound_Click_1(null, null);
        }
```

timeWatch is just a `Stopwatch` class and `bellMinutesFirst`/`bellSeconds`/`bellMinutesSecond` are just constants (integer).

I have tried changing the timercallback to 1000ms, but 2 problems:

1. the ring does not occur as accurate as i would like it to be.
2. it is not consistent, some times 2 rings are heard.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback you can keep track if your polling for the ringing, of if you are waiting for the 30s to pass after a ring. Something like this:

```
enum AutoRingStatus { Polling, Waiting }

AutoRingStatus _autoRingStatus = AutoRingStatus.Polling;
DateTime _autoRingWaitingTill = DateTime.Now;
private void autoRing(Object obj) {
    TimeSpan ts = timeWatch.Elapsed;

    if (ts.Minutes == bellMinutesFirst && ts.Seconds == bellSeconds || ts.Minutes == bellMinutesSecond && ts.Seconds == bellSeconds) {
        if (_autoRingStatus == AutoRingStatus.Polling) {
            btnSound_Click_1(null, null);
            _autoRingStatus = AutoRingStatus.Waiting;
            _autoRingWaitingTill = DateTime.Now.AddSecond(30);
        } else {
            if (_autoRingWaitingTill <= DateTime.Now) {
                _autoRingStatus = AutoRingStatus.Polling;
            } else {
                // Waiting for the 30s to pass...
            }
        }
    }
}
```